# Take input from user and verify if it is present in an array. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I take input from the user and check if the number is present in my array or not.
I need to generate random number from array1 and move it to array2. Then I need to let the user input a number and check if the number is present in array2 or not. I already have the first part figured out but need help with the second part which is taking input and checking it against array2.

Here's what I have so far

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const arr2 = []

const ran = () => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
  if(arr1.length>0)
  {
    arr2.push(arr1[index])
    arr1.splice(index, 1)
    
    const display = document.getElementById('array')
    display.innerText = ("\nArray 2 elements " + arr2.toString() + "\n Remaining Array 1 elements" + arr1.toString())
  }
  else
    {
      document.write("Array is now empty");
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick=ran()>click</button>
<span id='array' />
```

Comment: How abaout https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes ?

Comment: Your requirement is very simple as you already done with first part. To achieve second part you can use `array2.includes(userInput)` and based on the boolean value you can write your code.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you can just get an input with your desired method (I've used an `input` element), change it to a number, and check if it's in `array2`:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const arr2 = []

const ran = () => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
  if(arr1.length>0)
  {
    arr2.push(arr1[index])
    arr1.splice(index, 1)
    
    const display = document.getElementById('array')
    display.innerText = ("\nArray 2 elements " + arr2.toString() + "\n Remaining Array 1 elements" + arr1.toString())
  }
  else
    {
      document.write("Array is now empty");
    }
}

const checkUserInput = () => {
  let userInput = Number(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
  if (arr2.includes(userInput)) {
    console.log(`${userInput} in arr2`);
  } else console.log(`${userInput} not in arr2, at this time`);
  document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";
}
```

```html
<button onClick=ran()>click</button>
<span id='array'></span>
<br>
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="User input">
<button id="userInputCheck" onClick="checkUserInput()">Check Input</button>
```

Comment: I also want to display it to the user if the number is present in the array or now. How can I do that?

Comment: The answer already does that using `console.log()`. Do you need it to be rendered within the HTML instead?

Comment: Yes I need it rendered within HTML. I tried using `innerText` but that did not work. Maybe my code was not accurate